# Trying to use Xcode 9 to upload an app to iOS 11 devices, failed builds

Tags: ios, html, ios11, xcode9

I've uploaded effectively the same HTML 5 app (one html file plus a resourced library) using the previous version of *Xcode* and it worked fine going through iTunes Connect and onto the App Store but now with the latest *Xcode* it's not working. I've tried using *ObjectiveC* (previously the one I used successfully) and now Swift but I'm getting crashes.
*Xcode* is currently throwing up:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
>   *** First throw call stack:

I'm very new to all of this and it's not making sense to me! I managed to create another app of similar type at the same time and that's working using the same method!!

Line that crashes:          return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Comment: Add to your question your code including the line where it crashes

Comment: Apologies for being thick but what exactly would be useful to post, the XCode project? It's an HTML5 file plus resources folder that I've dragged into an Xcode project from Tumult Hype. I followed a tutorial on YouTube which showed me how to add what is now the (depracated) Web View and that was pretty much successful.

Comment: Just uploaded a PhoneGap build of the same project and it worked fine on TestFlight!